# HBase - Error while creating table

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to install Hbase(hbase-0.94.8).
I followed the steps given in this page
http://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/installing-pseudo-distributed-hbase-on-ubuntu/

I am able to start Hbase and enter into shell but when i type  create 't1','c1' from shell the following ERRORS were thrown

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 't1','c1'
14/03/15 10:23:16 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:18 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:19 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:21 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:23 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:27 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/15 10:23:31 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Here is some help for this command:
Create table; pass table name, a dictionary of specifications per
column family, and optionally a dictionary of table configuration.
Dictionaries are described below in the GENERAL NOTES section.
Examples:

  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
  hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true}
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']}
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {SPLITS_FILE => 'splits.txt'}
  hbase> # Optionally pre-split the table into NUMREGIONS, using
  hbase> # SPLITALGO ("HexStringSplit", "UniformSplit" or classname)
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}


hbase(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7
>   times

This means that the HBase master is not running. Please verify that it is running and then try creating your table again

Comment: What is the reason for the error shown above ?
Any idea, I am facing the same problem.